# How do I create unique values for labeling daylight saving extra hours?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pentaho

I need to manage daylight saving time data, so hours that repeat twice in my table or lack  data for that specific hour need to be coded with a unique value that will make me understand which hour corresponds to the daylight saving time hour. I am trying to do this in Pentaho Kettle

[image]

Comment: Show us some sample data.

Comment: I pasted a picture...the table comes from the provider and I am trying to alter it. As you can see the columns IDHG and IDHR will display discrepancies among one onother when there is passage from regular time to daylight saving hour. EVERY NUMBER REPRESENTS SEQUENTIALLY THAT SPECIFIC HOUR STARTING FROM MIDNIGHT CALLED HOUR ONE.

Comment: Adding the UTC time should do it.

Comment: IDHG represents the hours by daylight saving time hours, in fact twice a year you will see them doubled or not present. IDHR instead is a progressive count of the hours regardless of the daylight saving hour.

Comment: I am already using UTC, I have it in another column

Answer (score 0):

### If you need a sequence or timeseries, base it on UTC

There's a conflict in your requirements, because there just is no clean sequence to daylight saving time hours on the switching days that will still map automatically to a 24-hour clock.

If you use sequential numbers you end up with 23 or 25 records for the switching days, which means you would need to have a custom mapping back to UTC time to keep things working after hour 3. For any kind of time series, UTC is much more convenient and less error-prone.

If you keep 24 hours in a day and loosen the sequence, you will need to insert something like a 2.0 for the lost hour in spring and a 2.1 and 2.2 for the autumn switch. It just adds more complexity though:

- The dummy 2.0 record cannot have activity associated with it (as by definition it is skipped entirely) and if it had, it would break date parsing wherever you try to use it.
- The 2.1 and 2.2 records at least would help you see which activity occurred first, but you would need custom coding for this case everywhere, both splitting and merging the records from the double hour based on their UTC timestamps... notice a pattern here?

Comment: We are working with Italian timestamp, so UTC is not enough